# Proper way to pull in updates to Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

My app is currently running `Laravel Framework version 4.2.16`. I was attempting to use a nested relationship in a `whereHas` method and discovered that this is not possible in my version of Laravel.

However, when I visit the github page for the current `Builder.php` file, I noticed that code has been added to the framework to allow for nested relationships in a `whereHas` method.  Here's the link to the file:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php

What is the proper way to add these updates to my project? I ran `composer update`, but was told there was `Nothing to install or update`. How do I properly get this updated code into my project?

I suppose I am just confused as to what actually happens when a framework updates its code. Does this not mean that there is a new version available? Maybe I have to tell composer to use a specific commit rather than simply the version constraint I have now which is `"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"`?

**EDIT**
The `has`method in my app's version is:

```
/**
 * Add a relationship count condition to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $relation
 * @param  string  $operator
 * @param  int     $count
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public function has($relation, $operator = '>=', $count = 1, $boolean = 'and', Closure $callback = null)
{
        $relation = $this->getHasRelationQuery($relation);

        $query = $relation->getRelationCountQuery($relation->getRelated()->newQuery(), $this);

        if ($callback) call_user_func($callback, $query);

        return $this->addHasWhere($query, $relation, $operator, $count, $boolean);
}
```

However, the `has` method on Github is:

```
/**
 * Add a relationship count condition to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $relation
 * @param  string  $operator
 * @param  int     $count
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public function has($relation, $operator = '>=', $count = 1, $boolean = 'and', Closure $callback = null)
{
    if (strpos($relation, '.') !== false)
    {
        return $this->hasNested($relation, $operator, $count, $boolean, $callback);
    }
    $relation = $this->getHasRelationQuery($relation);
    $query = $relation->getRelationCountQuery($relation->getRelated()->newQuery(), $this);
    if ($callback) call_user_func($callback, $query);
    return $this->addHasWhere($query, $relation, $operator, $count, $boolean);
}
```

How do I properly pull this new `has` method into my project?

Comment: 4.2.16 does have the new whereHas method. (in fact every release in the 4.2 series has this method)

Comment: @WouterJ I'm not saying  I don't have the method. I'm saying that the method has changed since I created my project, and I would like to know how to get the updates.  See my edit.

Comment: I think you need to change your require to use `dev` like: `"laravel/framework": "4.2.*@dev"` so that it pulls from `dev-4.2` aka the branch 4.2. Otherwise i think it pulls from the tag matching your requirement which would be `4.2.16` which will not get the changes until a new 4.2.* tag i created. You can see the diffs here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/compare/v4.2.16...4.2